# Speaking of, [...] or Verbing, [...]

Tags: traducción, gramática, verbos, lingüística

I started out wondering if there was any Spanish analogy to the English construction `Speaking of, [independent clause]` as in

> Speaking of potatoes, I love them.

The most obvious possibility is

> Hablando de las papas, las amo.

but to my (untrained) ear this sounds weird.

---

Then I realized that in English, the construction `Verbing, [independent clause]` is more widespread. For example,

> Walking to the post office, I saw John.

In Spanish could this be

> Caminando a la oficina de correos, vi a John.

or would you have to say something like

> Mientras estaba caminando a la oficina de correos, vi a John.

? More importantly, *is this natural? Do people actually talk like this?*

Comment: Speaking of "speaking of", the Spanish construction is even more similar than you think, as you can drop the article and say just "hablando de papas". And welcome to [Spanish.SE], we hope you like our site!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like two separate questions, one about "speaking of" and the other about the "verbing".

The first one is simple: yes, you can say

> Hablando de papas [patatas], me encantan.

[A more interesting question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1584/12637) could be the use of the verb "amar", as it is a strong verb in some countries (in Spain we always try to avoid it and use "gustar", "encantar", "querer" and others; the English "I love you" is "te quiero" in Spain, not "te amo"). And the term "papas" is widely used in Latin America, but in Spain sounds a bit colloquial (maybe like the English "tater"), we prefer "patatas".

---

Regarding the other question, your options are just fine. Your sentences can be translated as you say. Here you have another option:

> De camino a Correos, vi a Juan. [In Spain the national company handling the posting service is "Correos", so we can use that name to replace "oficina de correos".]

Answer (score 3):

There are some expressions that are very natural in Spanish, for each of these.

> A propósito de la papa... ¿has probado alguna vez la papa amarilla del norte de Europa?  Es riquísima.
>
> Al caminar a la oficina de correos, vi a John.

Here's another example of that construction:

> Writing fast results in sloppy handwriting.  *Al escribir rápido, la letra no me sale muy clara.*

Your ideas and the others on this page do work, but I wanted to make you aware of these constructions.

By the way, for the particular example of walking to the post office, there's a great phrase, *camino a*, which means *on the way to*:

> Camino al correo me encontré a John.

For this phrase, you don't need to be on foot.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding *"Hablando de ..."*, that's exactly what we say.

> Speaking of Pedro, I saw him last night at the bar.
>   *Hablando de Pedro, lo vi anoche en el bar.*
>
> Speaking of dinner, what are you doing tomorrow night?
>   *Hablando de cenar, ¿qué haces mañana por la noche?*

Or the all-time famous (not a literal translation, but the equivalent saying in Spanish):

> Speak of the devil and he doth appear!
>   *¡Hablando del rey de Roma, por la puerta asoma!*

It's a very common idiom.

---

Regarding `[verb + ing] + independent clause`, your translation and use of the tense is also right. In Spanish those are just [subordinate adverbial sentences](http://iesbinef.educa.aragon.es/lengua/sintaxis/sintaxisweb/teoria.htm#a64) defining when the action is taking place:

> Walking to the post office, I saw John.
>   *Caminando a la oficina de correos, vi a John.*

And, just like in English, you can throw a "mientras" in there if you like:

> While I was walking to the post office, I saw John.
>   *Mientras iba caminando a la oficina de correos, vi a John.*
>   *Mientras caminaba hacia la oficina de correos, vi a John.*