# How to read a heart? (¿Cómo se lee un símbolo de un corazón?)

Tags: pronunciación, símbolos

I recently saw a magnet which read:

> Yo ❤ a mi perro

I realized that I'm unsure how the heart symbol would be read. In English, the most common readings would be *love* or, as a metonym, *heart*. I could come up with workable translations for Spanish, but I'm curious about what the most common reading(s) in Spanish is/are for this.

If region or dialect matter for the answer, I can't give good details. Where I live, Mexican Spanish is the most common I've encountered but far from the only variety. Worse, the magnet seemed like a mass-produced item and may relate to any region.

Comment: Just "amo a mi perro"

Comment: I'm the only freak who reads "Yo-corazón-mi perro" ha ha

Comment: My mind’s ear goes silent for a beat: I hear “Yo __ a mi perro.” Instead I process the meaning of the heart visually. I still get all the information though.

Answer (score 1):

The literal translation would be "Yo amo a mi perro", but you can skip the personal pronoun "I" and it would be "Amo a mi perro".

Also, "love" can be translated as "me encanta" (I like so much), but in the context that you have put it, this translation seems not to be the one because in that case the preposition "a" is skipped: "Me encanta mi perro".
Additionally, the verb "amar" has different connotations in different places, you can read [What is the difference among “querer”, “amar” and “adorar”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/what-is-the-difference-among-querer-amar-and-adorar) for more info.

Comment: In Spain, _amar_ in this context sounds quite strange. Related: [What is the difference among “querer”, “amar” and “adorar”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1584/1674)

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but could you clarify if you are reading the symbol as would be done in a Spanish-speaking area, or are translating the meaning of the magnet? As I mentioned in my question, perhaps not very clearly, translating the English meaning into Spanish isn't so challenging; I'm interested in the way that the heart symbol itself is most often read.

Comment: Emoticons symbols are an anglosaxon invention. Spanish speakers could read it as "Yo amo a mi perro", "Yo quiero a mi perro", "Adoro a mi perro" o "Me encanta mi perro", or even associating the symbol with the English word "love", but emoticons are not read in Spanish language.

Comment: If that's the case, would you consider updating your answer with that information? I understand that a heart symbol isn't a Spanish language character, and so doesn't have a pronunciation (it's the same in English). But I gave two examples of how an English speaker would read the sentence on the magnet aloud-- *love* or *heart*, and other readings might express the same idea but would be very unusual, sometimes to the extent of being "wrong". If the heart symbol has no colloquial reading, then that is the answer to my question.

Comment: I don't understand you. Your question if is an hearth symbol is read in a language compound by letters? If English speakers cant read a hearth symbol why Spanish speakers could do it? My answer is about how could be read following the meaning of an hearth symbol, and yes, has a colloquial meaning but not a literal reading because an image has not literal transliteration to words in any language compounded by letters.

Comment: It's easy to translate the meaning of the sentence in several ways, as you note, but that doesn't help me to know which of those ways would be most commonly used. As @fedorqui'SOstopharming' mentioned, using *amo* would seem odd in Spain, and so that would be a poor reading there. I'm looking for a good reading, and that often goes beyond a translation that is only technically correct.

Comment: Por ejemplo, λ es un carácter griego, y no tiene una pronunciación (en la manera de un fonema) en Ingles. Pero, un químico puede que leerlo como ¨wavelength¨ (longitud de onda) porque es el uso del carácter en este contexto. Similarmente, un dibujo de un corazón está leyendo en Ingles como ¨love¨ or ¨heart¨. Si haya un leerse común por el dibujo en español, es lo que quiero saber. (Lo siento por mi falta de habilidad en español, no tengo muchas oportunidades a practicar hoy en día. Pero probablemente me expresé pobremente en Ingles).

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' This sounds weird to my American ears too.